# Understanding color scales in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

There are so many ways to define colour scales within `ggplot2`. After just loading `ggplot2` I count `22` functions beginging with `scale_color_*` (or `scale_colour_*`) and same number beginging with `scale_fill_*`. Is it possible to briefly name the purpose of the functions below? Particularly I struggle with the differences of some of the functions and when to use them.

- scale_*_binned()
- scale_*_brewer()
- scale_*_continuous()
- scale_*_date()
- scale_*_datetime()
- scale_*_discrete()
- scale_*_distiller()
- scale_*_fermenter()
- scale_*_gradient()
- scale_*_gradient2()
- scale_*_gradientn()
- scale_*_grey()
- scale_*_hue()
- scale_*_identity()
- scale_*_manual()
- scale_*_ordinal()
- scale_*_steps()
- scale_*_steps2()
- scale_*_stepsn()
- scale_*_viridis_b()
- scale_*_viridis_c()
- scale_*_viridis_d()

**What I tried**

I've tried to make some research on the web but the more I read the more I get onfused. To drop some random example: ["The default scale for continuous fill scales is `scale_fill_continuous()` which in turn defaults to `scale_fill_gradient()`"](https://ggplot2-book.org/scale-colour.html). I do not get what the [difference](https://www.google.com/search?q=scale_fill_continuous%28%29+scale_fill_gradient%28%29+difference&rlz=1C1GCEU_deDE819DE819&sxsrf=APq-WBs0VkTEWHyLu-Z84WLSQPGC7BOv4g%3A1643726057165&ei=6UT5YZbACfPd7_UPwd6m-Aw&ved=0ahUKEwjW2Prd3N71AhXz7rsIHUGvCc8Q4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=scale_fill_continuous%28%29+scale_fill_gradient%28%29+difference&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BwgAEEcQsAM6BAgAEB46BggAEAoQHjoHCCEQChCgAToFCCEQoAFKBAhBGABKBAhGGABQ3ANYwhhgrRpoAnACeACAAb4BiAHJDZIBBDEuMTKYAQCgAQGgAQLIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz) of both functions is. Again, this is just an example. Same is true for `scale_color_binned()` and `scale_color_discrete()` where I can not name the difference. And in case of `scale_color_date()` and `scale_color_datetime()` the destription says "`scale_*_gradient` creates a two colour gradient (low-high), `scale_*_gradient2` creates a diverging colour gradient (low-mid-high), `scale_*_gradientn` creates a n-colour gradient." which is nice to know but how is this related to `scale_color_date()` and `scale_color_datetime()`? Looking for those functions on the web does not give me very informative sources either. Reading on this topic gets also chaotic because there are tons of color palettes in different packages which are sequential/ diverging/ qualitative plus one can set same color in different ways, i.e. by color name, rgb, number, hex code or palette name. In part this is not directly related to the question about the `2*22` functions but in some cases it is because providing a "wrong" palette results in an error (e.g. the error`"Continuous value supplied to discrete scale`).

**Why I ask this**

I need to do many plots for my work and I am supposed to provide some function that returns all kind of plots. The plots are supposed to have similiar layout so that they fit well together. One aspect I need to consider here is that the colour scales of the plots go well together. See [here](https://datavizproject.com/) for example, where so many different kind of plots have same colour scale. I was hoping I could use some general function which provides a colour palette to *any* data, regardless of whether the data is continuous or categorical, whether it is a fill or col easthetic. But since this is not how colour scales are defined in `ggplot2` I need to understand what all those functions are good for.

Comment: You might want to read the Hadley Wickham's book "ggplot2: elegant graphics for data analysis" which is online [at this URL](https://ggplot2-book.org/). The chapter on color scales is number 11.

Comment: @KoenV The one quote in the question is from this book. The chapter about colour scales seems rather like an unstructural collection of some examples how one can add colour scales. It seems to be made for recipe cooking and does not systematically describe the 12 ways one can set colour scaes in ggplot2.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This is a good question... and I would have hoped there would be a practical guide somewhere.  One could question if SO would be a good place to ask this question, but regardless, here's my attempt to summarize the various `scale_color_*()` and `scale_fill_*()` functions built into `ggplot2`.  Here, we'll describe the range of functions using `scale_color_*()`; however, the same general rules will apply for `scale_fill_*()` functions.

## Overall Categorization

There are 22 functions in all, but happily we can group them intelligently based on practical usage scenarios.  There are three key criteria that can be used to define practically how to use each of the `scale_color_*()` functions:

1. **Nature of the mapping data**.  Is the data mapped to the color aesthetic *discrete* or *continuous*?  *CONTINUOUS* data is something that can be explained via real numbers: time, temperature, lengths - these are all continuous because even if your observations are `1` and `2`, there can exist something that would have a theoretical value of `1.5`.  *DISCRETE* data is just the opposite: you cannot express this data via real numbers.  Take, for example, if your observations were: `"Model A"` and `"Model B"`.  There is no obvious way to express something in-between those two. As such, you can only represent these as single colors or numbers.
2. **The Colorspace**.  The color palette used to draw onto the plot.  By default, `ggplot2` uses (I believe) a color palette based on evenly-spaced hue values.  There are other functions built into the library that use either Brewer palettes or Viridis colorspaces.
3. **The level of Specification**.  Generally, once you have defined if the scale function is continuous and in what colorspace, you have variation on the level of control or specification the user will need or *can* specify.  A good example of this is the functions: `*_continuous()`, `*_gradient()`, `*_gradient2()`, and `*_gradientn()`.

## Continuous Scales

We can start off with *continuous* scales.  These functions are all used when applied to observations that are continuous variables (see above).  The functions here can further be defined if they are either *binned* or *not binned*.  "Binning" is just a way of grouping ranges of a continuous variable to all be assigned to a particular color.  You'll notice the effect of "binning" is to change the legend keys from a "colorbar" to a "steps" legend.

The continuous example (colorbar legend):

```
library(ggplot2)
cont <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp, color=cyl)) + geom_point(size=4)

cont + scale_color_continuous()
```

[image]

The binned example (color steps legend):

```
cont + scale_color_binned()
```

[image]

The following are *continuous* functions.

| Name of Function | Colorspace | Legend | What it does |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| scale_color_continuous() | default | Colorbar | basic scale (as if you did nothing) |
| scale_color_gradient() | user-defined | Colorbar | define `low` and `high` values |
| scale_color_gradient2() | user-defined | Colorbar | define `low` `mid` and `high` values |
| scale_color_gradientn() | user_defined | Colorbar | define any number of incremental val |
| scale_color_binned() | default | Colorsteps | basic scale, but binned |
| scale_color_steps() | user-defined | Colorsteps | define `low` and `high` values |
| scale_color_steps2() | user-defined | Colorsteps | define `low`, `mid`, and `high` vals |
| scale_color_stepsn() | user-defined | Colorsteps | define any number of incremental vals |
| scale_color_viridis_c() | Viridis | Colorbar | viridis color scale. Change palette via `option=`. |
| scale_color_viridis_b() | Viridis | Colorsteps | Viridis color scale, binned. Change palette via `option=`. |
| scale_color_distiller() | Brewer | Colorbar | Brewer color scales. Change palette via `palette=`. |
| scale_color_fermenter() | Brewer | Colorsteps | Brewer color scale, binned. Change palette via `palette=`. |

## Discrete Scales

These *discrete* scales apply only when the data mapped is *discrete* (see above).  Since the nature and colors of discrete scales are more disjointed by definition, these tend to be more manually-defined.  We can use the same `mtcars` example and "force" a discrete scale applied to the color by mapping to `cyl` defined `as.factor()`:

```
discrete <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp, color=as.factor(cyl))) + geom_point(size=4)
discrete
```

[image]

The following are *discrete* scale functions:

| Name of Function | What it does |
| --- | --- |
| scale_color_discrete() | The basic default. Evenly-spaced hues |
| scale_color_hue() | Same as `scale_color_discrete()`, but you can define the range of hues and colors used |
| scale_color_grey() | Uses a greyscale. Can define the range. |
| scale_color_manual() | Must define specifically every color used. You can apply to your mapping by supplying a named vector for `values=`. |
| scale_color_identity() | A special-case function where your data is made up of names of colors - not names of factor levels |
| scale_color_brewer() | The discrete version of the **Brewer** colorspaces. Change palette via `palette=`. |
| scale_color_viridis_d() | The discrete version of the **viridis** colorspaces. Can change palette via `option=`. |

## Viridis and Brewer Scales

A final note, you'll see above defined the functions for Brewer and Viridis palette options.  Each one of these contain a few color palettes chosen to better represent ordered and non-ordered data based on some color theory.  It's useful to do a little research in color theory applied to data visualization on your own.  There are discrete, continuous, and binned versions of each of the two function classes, and each one has a slightly different method to change the specific palette.  You'll have to Google around a bit for some representations of each scale to get a feel for them, but useful usage notes include:

| Colorspace | Discrete version | Continuous version | Binned version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Brewer** | scale_color_brewer() | scale_color_distiller() | scale_color_fermenter() |
| **Viridis** | scale_color_viridis_d() | scale_color_viridis_c() | scale_color_viridis_b() |

One final note here: `scale_color_ordinal()` is really the same as `scale_color_viridis_d()`... I honestly don't really see the difference, so perhaps one is just a wrapper for the other?

## Date Scales

The final two more esoteric functions are the ones related to *date* and *datetime*.  These functions are `scale_color_date()` and `scale_color_datetime()`, respectively.  They are basically the same as the `scale_color_continuous()` function, but with some convenience wrappers for labeling dates.  This is the same relationship that `scale_x_date()` has with `scale_x_continuous()`.

```
ggplot(economics, aes(x=date, y=unemploy, fill=date)) + geom_col() +scale_fill_date()
```

[image]

You see the graphic result is the same as `scale_color_continuous()`, but note the formatting benefit for representing dates correction using `scale_color_date()`:

```
ggplot(economics, aes(x=date, y=unemploy, fill=date)) + geom_col() +scale_fill_continuous()
```

[image]

## It all makes sense...

Given all of this above... now the following error messages you have probably seen before become quite apparent:

```
> discrete + scale_color_continuous()
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

> cont + scale_color_discrete()
Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale
```

Comment: With `ggplot2`, there are a lot of functions that are "wrapper" or "convenience" functions.  They seem duplicative because they literally *are* - functions that are innately calling another function with a specific set of arguments.  `scale_*` functions are littered with this type of thing, and they make plotting a lot easier.  So, from a development, choice, it's quite sensible when you constantly use a lot of these in practice.

Comment: And really: Your answer is outstanding. It is far the systematic source describing colour scaling!!

Comment: For the viridis and brewer functions, they refer to colorspaces differently, so the functions themselves have to be different.  Moreover, the algorithms used to adjust and move along the color palettes are quite different, so definitely there's not a good way to combine these functions.  Also, Brewer color palettes can be similar to some of the viridis color palettes, yes, but they are different in form and design.

Comment: As for binned vs. continuous - both are ordered data, and "binning" can only happen with continuous data.  Behind the scenes, the same basic principles are applied when creating histograms (which also bin continuous data using `stat_bin`).

Comment: Final note on colorspaces.  Color theory is more about *how the colors are chosen* than *the colors themselves*.  The hue-based method focuses on an even spacing of hues, but this is fundamentally different than how colors are selected for Brewer scales, which are different than viridis.  It's hard to get into here in the comments (and I'm no expert), but the scales are created from completely different ways of thinking about how to communicate information via color.  As for `scale_any()`... a good idea!  Give it a try to code your own function :)

Comment: This is a very nice answer @chemdork123. It would probably make a good community wiki, as I haven't seen all this put together in one place before, and it is more helpful than the docs are for scales.

Comment: one doesn’t need to google too much for a good representation of the brewer scales: check colorbrewer2.org

Comment: chemdork would you mind incorporating some of the comments into your answer instead? I find some of the thoughts might deserve a more prominent position, also comments can be deleted without a trace.

Comment: I think I found some special case which is not included in the 2*22 functions. At the same time the requested color scaling function seems quite obvious to me. If you are interested you can see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71085867/ggplot-scale-color-steps-like-color-scale-for-ordered-factors

Comment: Looking at the source for `scale_fill_ordinal`, it sets the `type` according to the option `ggplot2.ordinal.(fill|color)`; if it is not set, it defaults to `scale_fill_viridis_d`. In other words, the user can specify a palette / option for an ordinal scale, which might be different from viridis.

Answer (score 3):

@chemdork123 provided an outstanding answer. I want to add on it since my question was focussing on the differences between the numerous color scale functions or, to rephrase it: Why do we need them all? Can't we embrace them in less functions?

I will show what I mean by providing two general functions that produce the same outputs as the corresponding 10 original functions. It is pretty easy to understand how more original functions can be summarized in general functions, too.

**General form of scale_**distiller, scale***viridis_c and scale**_continuous**

How the function works:

- (1) Decide what original function to use depending on palette name. With this first step we save choosing between `scale_*_distiller`, `scale_*_viridis_c` and `scale_*_continuous`.
- (2) I define the `aesthetics` argument as `c("colour", "fill")`. This way we do not need to choose whether the aesthetic is a `col` or `fill` color, i.e. we half the amount of functions.
- (3) All other arguments can be passed on to the according color scale function.

The function is:

```
scale_col_fill_cont <- function(palette, ...){
  rcb <- c("Blues", "BuGn", "BuPu", "GnBu", "Greens", "Greys", "Oranges", "OrRd", "PuBu",
           "PuBuGn", "PuRd", "Purples", "RdPu", "Reds", "YlGn", "YlGnBu", "YlOrBr", "YlOrRd",
           "Accent", "Dark2", "Paired", "Pastel1", "Pastel2", "Set1", "Set2", "Set3",
           "BrBG", "PiYG", "PRGn", "PuOr", "RdBu", "RdGy", "RdYlBu", "RdYlGn", "Spectral")
  rcb_num <- 1:18
  v <- c("magma", "inferno", "plasma", "viridis", "cividis", "rocket", "mako", "turbo",
         "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H")


  if(any(palette == rcb) | any(palette == rcb_num)){
    scale_color_distiller(palette= palette, aesthetics= c("colour", "fill"), ...)   
  } else if(any(palette == v)){
    scale_color_viridis_c(option= palette, aesthetics= c("colour", "fill"), ...)
  } else{
    scale_color_continuous(type= palette, aesthetics= c("colour", "fill"), ...)
 }
}
```

**General form of scale_**gradient and scale**_gradient2**

How the function works:

- (1) Check whether the `mid` argument is provided, if not use scale_*_gradient2.
- (2) to (3) same as above.

The function is:

```
scale_col_fill_gradient <- function(low, mid, high, ...){
  if(missing(mid)){
    scale_color_gradient(low= low, high= high, aesthetics= c("colour", "fill"), ...)
  } else{
    scale_color_gradient2(low= low, mid= mid, high= high, aesthetics= c("colour", "fill"), ...)
  }
}
```

---

**Examples**

First we need some data and ggplot objects:

```
# Data
n <- 10
df <- data.frame(a= 1:n, x= rnorm(n), y= rnorm(n), z= rnorm(n))

# ggplot objects
library(ggplot2)
gg_col <- ggplot(data= df, aes(x, y, col= z)) +
  geom_point()
gg_fill <- ggplot(data= df, aes(a, group= a, fill= z)) +
  geom_bar()
```

Here are the general functions in action. The examples in the table produce the same output for the general function as for the original functions.

| Original function names | General function name | Examples |
| --- | --- | --- |
| scale_color_continuous(), scale_fill_continuous(), scale_color_viridis_c, scale_fill_viridis_c, scale_color_distiller(), scale_color_distiller() | scale_col_fill_cont | **Vidris** # Applying to a col aesthetic gg_col + scale_col_fill_cont("rocket") gg_col + scale_color_viridis_c(option= "rocket") # Applying to a fill aesthetic gg_fill + scale_col_fill_cont("rocket") gg_fill + scale_fill_viridis_c(option= "rocket") **RColorBrewer** # Applying to a col aesthetic gg_col + scale_col_fill_cont("Spectral") gg_col + scale_color_distiller(palette= "Spectral") # Applying to a fill aesthetic gg_fill + scale_col_fill_cont(3) gg_fill + scale_fill_distiller(palette= 3) **scale_*_continuous()** # Applying to a col aesthetic gg_col + scale_col_fill_cont("gradient") gg_col + scale_color_continuous(type= "gradient") # Applying to a fill aesthetic gg_fill + scale_col_fill_cont("viridis") gg_fill + scale_fill_continuous(type= "viridis") |
| scale_color_gradient, scale_fill_gradient, scale_color_gradient2, scale_fill_gradient2 | scale_col_fill_gradient | **scale_*_gradient** # Applying to a col aesthetic gg_col + scale_color_gradient(low= "yellow", high= "red") gg_col + scale_col_fill_gradient(low= "yellow", high= "red") # Applying to a fill aesthetic gg_fill + scale_fill_gradient(low= "yellow", high= "red") gg_fill + scale_col_fill_gradient(low= "yellow", high= "red") **scale_*_gradient2** # Applying to a col aesthetic gg_col + scale_color_gradient2(low= "yellow", mid= "white", high= "red") gg_col + scale_col_fill_gradient(low= "yellow", mid= "white",high= "red") # Applying to a fill aesthetic gg_fill + scale_fill_gradient2(low= "yellow", mid= "white", high= "red") gg_fill + scale_col_fill_gradient(low= "yellow", mid= "white",high= "red") |

Comment: I think you really might wanna have a look at the paletteer package. https://cran.r-project.org/package=paletteer and for your convenience the github readme https://github.com/EmilHvitfeldt/paletteer

Comment: @tjebo Sounds like the idea of more general function is not that far-fetched. Thank you!

Comment: if you consider making a more generalised function and packaging this, I strongly recommend digging into the source code of paletteer. I’m sure there are a lot of very clever thoughts in there, and you don’t need to rethink everything twice.

Comment: @tjebo Your are right. Thanks. I am not going to do a package about it. Updated my answer for a second general function. I guess it gets clear that this can easily be done.

Comment: To answer your general question as to "why"... well, you'd have to ask Hadley Wickham (I think he's the one who coded `ggplot2`).  Ultimately, it's a subjective question related to abstraction.  Often a choice comes up in programming functions when you have the option to code variants of that function within the arguments, or make new functions.  In the case of `ggplot2`, the choice was often to do both: we have the core function available - ex.  `scale_*_continuous()` - for specific control and the wrapper/convenience functions like `scale_*_distiller()` and `scale_*_viridis_c()`.

Comment: @chemdork123 " it's a subjective question" - great! I just wanted to make sure I did not get anything wrong by assuming one can build more general functions. Thanks again.

Comment: You see this way of thinking throughout `ggplot2` - where we get the convenience functions + the core ones.  Very obvious for all `scale_` functions, but also in various `geom_` functions (i.e. `geom_col()` kind of a wrapper for `geom_bar(stat="identity"...`, and then there's all the `theme_*()` functions, which are wrappers for specific mixes of `theme()` elements...  we see the wrapper functions + the core functions themselves.  It can get complicated, but offers a balance of useability + depth of control.

Comment: @chemdork123 My subjective view: Often I simply want a quick and dirty solution, e.g. I want to add a color palette without thinking which of the 44 functions to take. So personally, I prefer more general functions and in some cases like with my general version of scale_*_gradient and scale_*_gradient2 I see little drawbacks of a general function - if no 'mid' argument is provided, then don't use one. That seems way easier to me. So either I'll make my personal general function over time or, I'll come back again and again and look up the correct function in your post :-D Which is very likely..