# Remembering steps in R

Tags: r

I am a beginner in R and it might appear irrelevant. But can anyone tell me how to remember **syntax**? like arguments of ggplot or tidyverse or any other package.

Comment: `?ggplot` or maybe `args(ggplot)` is sufficient for you or just type `ggplot` and it will display the source.

Comment: Just use it a lot. I found it not intuitive at first but just by using it a lot it became second nature.

Comment: Also if you're using Rstudio (which I *highly* recommend) there are a lot of useful tool-tip and autocompletions to help with remembering what arguments each function takes without even having to pull the help on that function.

Comment: Dan Adams is absolutely right, using it allot and RStudio helps allot. I tend to keep 1 script file open just for notes/ handy syntaxs I will probably have to reuse in the future.

Comment: Thank you very much @DanAdams, G.Grothendieck,omniswitcher

Comment: Good luck and stick with it! Also come back here often to ask questions, but put in time to make them *good* questions. You'll learn a lot by doing the research first and carefully preparing your question. Most times you'll answer the question yourself before even posting just by working to clearly articulate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do that. You can start writing the function and press TAB, it will appear in a pop up. You can also check the cheatsheet, here are some
examples: https://www.rstudio.com/resources/cheatsheets/

Or you can check the help topic by writing the function with a `?` in it's start, for example: `?ggplot`

Answer (score 0):

OP, your question does not relate to coding per se - no problem to solve via issues with code - so it's not really *supposed* to be on SO.  With that being said, it is a viable question and very daunting to approach using `ggplot2` to create plots when you really don't have the background for doing so.  Consequently, I think you still deserve a good answer, so here are some principles to help out a new user.

### Know where to get information

The biggest help to offer is to practice.  You will become more familiar with usage, but even "the pros" forget the argument syntax and what stuff does.  In this case, the following is helpful:

- **Use [RStudio](https://www.rstudio.com/)**.  The base R terminal is fully capable; however, RStudio brings a ton of conveniences that make programming in R so much easier.  Tooltips are an important part of how I create and use functions in R.  If you start typing out a function, you'll be presented with a short list of arguments:

[image]

What's more, you can start typing an argument and you'll get a description from the help directly within RStudio:

[image]

- **Check the help for functions.**  This one should be obvious, but I am constantly checking the help for functions on CRAN.  This is easily done in RStudio by typing `?` before the function.  So, if I need to know the arguments and syntax for `geom_point()`, I'll type `?geom_point` into the console and you'll get the documentation directly within RStudio.
- **Online Resources.** A quick search online can give you a lot of information (maybe even this answer).  There are a lot of other resources: here too.  Including [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/index.html), [here](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/ggplot2-package.html), [here](https://bookdown.org/rdpeng/RProgDA/basic-plotting-with-ggplot2.html), and [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/).

### Become familiar with the Principles of plotting in `ggplot2`

Knowing where to get information is helpful, but sometimes you feel so lost that you don't even know *what information you actually are looking to get*.  This is the crux of many of the questions here on SO related to `ggplot2`, which is: "how can I change my axes?", "How do I change colors in the plot?", or "How can I get a legend to show x, y, or z?".  Sometimes you can google, but often it's not even clear *what* you are looking to find.

This is where a fundamental understanding of how to create a plot in `ggplot2` becomes useful.  I'll go through how I always approach plotting in `ggplot2` and hopefully this will help you out a bit.

#### Step 1 - prepare data

Making your data prepared to plot is exceptionally useful, and sometimes difficult to do.  It's a bit beyond what I intend to communicate here, but a mandatory piece of reading would be regarding [Tidy Data Principles](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html).

#### Step 2 - Think about Mapping

Mapping is often overlooked in the process, but in short, this is *how the columns of your dataset relate to the plot*.  It's easy to say "this column will be my x axis" and "this column will be my y axis", but you should also be clear on if the values of other columns will relate to color, fill, size, shape, etc etc... Thinking this way, it will soon be quite obvious why you would want to get Step 1 correct above, because only Tidy data will be able to be used directly in mapping without issue.

#### Step 3 - The Fundamental `ggplot()` call

The first step in *plotting* will be your first call to `ggplot()`.  Here you need to assign data - example via `df %>% ggplot(...)` or `ggplot(data=df, ...)`.  This is also *typically* where you would setup at least your x and y axes via *mapping*.  You can just stop here (x and y axes), or you can specify the other aesthetics in the mapping here too.  Ultimately, this alone plotted "sets up" the plot.  If we just plot the result of that, you get the following:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg))
p
```

[image]

#### Step 4 - Add your geoms

A "geom" (short for "geometry") describes the shapes and "things" on your plot that will be positioned on the x and y axes.  You can add any number, but in this example, we'll add points.  If all you want to do is plot the observations at the x and y axes, you just need to add `geom_point()` and that should be enough:

```
p + geom_point()
```

[image]

#### Step 5 - Adding Legends

Note we don't have a legend yet.  This is because there are no aesthetics mapped other than x and y.  `ggplot2` creates legends automatically when you specify in the `mapping` (via `aes()`) a characteristic way of differentiating the way we draw a geom.  In other words, we can describe `color=` within `aes()` and that will initiate the creation of a legend.  You can do the same with other aesthetics too.

```
p + geom_point(aes(color=cyl))
```

[image]

This creates a legend type depending on the type of data mapped.  So, a colorbar legend is created here because the column `mtcars$cyl` is numeric.  If we use a non-numeric column, you get a discrete legend:

```
p + geom_point(aes(color=rownames(mtcars)))
```

[image]

There's advanced stuff too... but not covered here.

#### Step 6 - Adjusting the Scales

All we do when you specify mapping (i.e. `aes(color = ...),`) is how the data is mapped to that aesthetic.  This *does not specify the actual color* to be used.  If you don't specify, the default coloring or sizing is used, but sometimes you want to change that.  You can do that via `scale_*_()` functions... of which there are many depending on your application.  For information on color scales, [you can see this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70945499/9664796)... but suffice it to say this is quite a complicated part of the plotting stuff that depends greatly on what you want to do.  Many of the `scale_()` functions are structured similarly, so you can probably get an idea of what you can do with that answer and see.  Here's an example of how we can adjust the color with one of these functions:

```
p + geom_point(aes(color=cyl)) +
  scale_color_gradient(low="red", high="green")
```

[image]

#### Step 7 - Adjusting Labels

Here I usually add the plot labels and axis labels.  You can conviently use `ylab()`, or `xlab()` or `ggtitle()` to assign axis labels and the title, or just define them all together with `labs(y = ..., x = ..., title = ...)`.  You can also use this time to format and arrange things associated with legends and scales (tick marks and whatnot) via `guides(...)` (for legends) or the `scale_x_*()` and `scale_y_*()` functions (for tick marks on axes).

#### Step 8 - Theme Elements

Finally, you can change the overall look with various ggplot themes.  An [account of default themes is given here](https://rpubs.com/Mentors_Ubiqum/default_themes), but you can extend that with the `ggtheme` package [to get more](https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2016-12-03/web/packages/ggthemes/vignettes/ggthemes.html).  You might want to just change a few specific elements of size, color, linetype, etc on the plot.  You can address these specific elements via `theme()`.  A [helpful list of theme elements is given here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html).

So, putting it all together you have:

```
# initial call
ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg)) +
  
  # geoms
  geom_point(aes(color=cyl), size=3) +
  
  # define the color scale
  scale_color_viridis_c() +
  
  # define labels and ticks and stuff
    # axis
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 600, by=50)) +
  
    # legend ticks
    guides(color=guide_colorbar(ticks.colour = "black", ticks.linewidth = 3)) +
  
  # Labels
  labs(x="Disp", y="Miles per gallon (mpg)", color = "# of \ncylinders", title="Ugly Plot 1.0") +
  
  # theme and theme elements
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill="gray90"),
    panel.grid.major = element_line(color="gray20", linetype=2, size=0.2),
    panel.grid.minor = element_line(color="gray70", linetype=2, size=0.1),
    axis.text = element_text(size=12, face = "bold"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle=30, hjust=1)
  )
```

[image]

It's a lot of steps, but I break it down like that basically every time.  When plot code gets large, I break up the chunks much in that manner above to help clear my mind on how to create the plot.

Comment: The majority of this answers a question that wasn't asked. The beginning part, finding code documentation, is relevant to this question, even though the question is too broad for SO. The ggplot part is a very good answer, but not to this question—it would make for a great tutorial or blog post somewhere else