# RColorBrewer Attempt apply non-function error

Tags: r, ggplot2

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggspatial)
ggplot(inner_join_schools_sf, aes(fill = Avg_Math_Prof)) +
      annotation_map_tile(type = "osm") +
    geom_sf(size = 0.3) + 
      scale_fill_continuous(palette = "Greens")
```

I am trying to fill in a choropleth map in R with the above code, and I get the error

> Error in self$palette(uniq) : attempt to apply non-function.

I cannot find anything wrong with the syntax, and the code runs if I simply type `scale_fill_continuous()` and do not specify a palette at all. What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Perhaps you meant `scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Greens")`?

Comment: That does work, but is there a reason that ``scale_fill_continuous(palette = 
"Greens")`` wouldn't also work?

Comment: There are variety of color scales and they use different parameters. This great SO answer provides a comprehensive review of them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70942728/understanding-color-scales-in-ggplot2/70945499#70945499