# geom_point - change colour of variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, aes, geom-point

[image]

I coloured my data by "Full Bath", however it is a similar shade & unclear.

I am trying to change the colour by variable of "Full Bath" to be more clear.

Could anyone help :)

This is what I have:

```
data %>%
  ggplot(aes(Sale.Price, Total.Bsmt.SF)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = Full.Bath)) + geom_smooth()
```

Comment: You need two curves instead of one and each in a different color, is that right ?

Comment: thanks for getting back so fast! I am doing a scatter plot and am finding it very difficult to explain it so I attached a photo. Colours 2&3 are very similar and I am trying to change them! Apologies and thanks!!

Comment: You only want to change the colors, nothing more ?

Comment: Yep, only want to change the colours

Comment: I updated my answer, it should work now with your dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To manually change the colors, you can use `scale_color_manual`, as follows:

```
### Simulation of data
set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(Sale.Price=rnorm(100, 100, 10), 
                   Total.Bsmt.SF=rnorm(100, 10, 1),
                   Full.Bath=rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), 20))

### Plot data
data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Sale.Price, y = Total.Bsmt.SF)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = Full.Bath)) + 
  geom_smooth() + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#84d58d", "#84c1d5", "#9e84d5", "#d584b0", "#d5be84"))
```

[image]

Link for colors selection
https://htmlcolorcodes.com/fr/

Comment: Perfect! thanks so much for your help! been at that for ages

Comment: The following could help you in the future ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70942728/understanding-color-scales-in-ggplot2